# How to make checkbox in alert dialog align left?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

It is possible to modified the checkbox align left in alert dialog?

### this is activity.java file

```
AlertDialog dialog; 

final CharSequence[] items = {" Easy "," Medium "," Hard "," Very Hard "};
            // arraylist to keep the selected items
            final ArrayList seletedItems=new ArrayList();

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Select The Difficulty Level");
            builder.setMultiChoiceItems(items, null,
                    new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
             // indexSelected contains the index of item (of which checkbox checked)
             @Override
             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int indexSelected,
                     boolean isChecked) {
                 if (isChecked) {
                     // If the user checked the item, add it to the selected items
                     // write your code when user checked the checkbox 
                     seletedItems.add(indexSelected);
                 } else if (seletedItems.contains(indexSelected)) {
                     // Else, if the item is already in the array, remove it 
                     // write your code when user Uchecked the checkbox 
                     seletedItems.remove(Integer.valueOf(indexSelected));
                 }
             }
         })
          // Set the action buttons
         .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                 //  Your code when user clicked on OK
                 //  You can write the code  to save the selected item here

             }
         })
         .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                //  Your code when user clicked on Cancel

             }
         });

            dialog = builder.create();//AlertDialog dialog; create like this outside onClick
            dialog.show();
    }
```

.........................................................................

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTpYb.jpg">

but... I want the checkbox displayed at the left side...anyone help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can put  custom view in your alertdialog.  In that view you can easily align your checkbox where you want. For more read this tutorial. http://www.pcsalt.com/android/create-alertdialog-with-custom-layout/#sthash.yN5edpAX.FKWQjxBj.dpbs

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
dialog = builder.create();
dialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
dialog.show();
```

Comment: Still got the same result. The checkbox not align to the left :(